# Bubbling scope - Updating var from nested function

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope

I'm updating a variable from an outer scope in a nested function,
as this is happening during a init function the outer scope isn't the outermost (window) scope;

```
var init = function() {

  var x = 'old stuff' ;      

        function butClick() {
          x = 'new stuff' ; 
        }
  console.log(x); //  new stuff

  document.querySelector("btn").addEventListener("click", butClick, false);
}
window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

in order to save it in the init-function scope I'm omitting the **var** keyword and as expected the new value of the variable bubbles up and updates;

but the result of  `console.log('x' in window )`  is false,
isn't the bubbling supposed to get to the window scope?

Comment: There are no events here, the `event-bubbling` tag is irrelevant.

Comment: You're right, I updated code example

Comment: I've updated the answer to address the edit. It still doesn't change what gets logged, and still doesn't create a global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is declared within your `init` function, so no, `x` within that function (or anything inside it) won't resolve to a global.

---

Separately, a comment in your question's code :

```
console.log(x) //  new stuff
```

...implying that `x` will be "new stuff" at that point. It won't. You haven't *called* `butClick` anywhere, so `x` will have its original "old stuff" value.

If you *did* call `butClick` at some point, it would update the `x` that's local to `init`. It wouldn't create or update a global.

---

Re your update setting `butClick` as an event handler: The comment suggesting `x` should be "new stuff" is still wrong. As of the time that `console.log` line runs, `x` has the value "old stuff". ***Later***, if someone clicks the button, `x` will be updated by `butClick`, but that won't retroactively re-run the `console.log` line.

But even when called in response to a click, `butClick` is still updating the `x` within `init`, not a global. Variable scope is lexically-determined, not determined by where a function is called *from*.

Comment: is there a way if I wanted it to become global after first click?

Comment: @maioman: In the browser environment, you can always create globals by assigning to properties on the global object, which you can reference via its property `window`. So: `window.x = "some value";` creates or updates a global `x` variable.